# Incorrect stack data in Wing IDE with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, wing-ide

I am using Wing to write and debug a Tkinter GUI. I am finding that the Stack Data View doesn't seem to match the actual attributes of my widgets. Take this code for example:

```
import Tkinter
import ttk

root = Tkinter.Tk()
checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Test Check Button")
print checkbutton.text
```

This gives me an attribute error at the last line. However, when I look at the stack, there is clearly an attribute called 'text' with the value that I'm looking for:

[image: Wing screen capture]

Anyone know what's going on?

I'm using:

- Wing version: Wing IDE Pro 5.1.3-1 (rev 33002)
- Tkinter version: '$Revision: 81008 $'
- Python version: 2.7.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this to the Wing email list, and I got the following response from the developers:

> It looks like a `ttk.Checkbutton` defines `keys()` and `__getitem__()`
>   methods to exposes tk attributes via `checkbutton[<name>]`.  Because
>   of the `keys()` and `__getitem__()`, Wing is displaying the instance
>   as if it were a dictionary, with the keys and values interspersed with
>   the attributes. Wing does this because often you want to view an
>   object that defines `keys()` and `__getitem__()` as if it were a
>   dictionary, but I agree that it's confusing in this instance.
>
> We'll try to improve this in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling attributes are not object attributes. Widgets use an internal system for managing the widget options. `.text` is not an attribute, which is why you get the error. To reference the configuration use `.cget(...)` to get the value and `.configure(...)` to change the value.

Comment: That's true, but I'm not so much confused about the attribute error as I am about the presence of a .text attribute in the stack data. Why is Wing showing me an attribute that doesn't actually exist?

Comment: @Emma I think that at least logically (from an OO point of view) `text` is considered an attribute, and that's probably why Wing developers decided to include it as an attribute.